# Why CORS policy blocks request only when I dump?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, cors, dump, nelmiocorsbundle

I had problem on my Vue, Symfony (using Docker for setup) project with CORS policy that blocked my requests on API so I included nelmio-cors-bundle and set it up so regular responces work now.

Here is my nelmio config:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
    expose_headers: ['Link']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': null
```

And here is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/movement-types")
 */
public function getMovementTypes(MovementTypeRepository $repo): Response
{
    $items = $repo->findAll();
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode($items));
    return $response;
}
```

So far this works. But whenever I add dump() of var_dump() function into the controller CORS policy blocks it again. I tried to change the nelmio config to the most inclusive setting possible, but it didn't work either.

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
    allow_origin: ['*']
    allow_methods: ['*']
    allow_headers: ['*']
    expose_headers: ['Link']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': null
```

I tried also this, even though I don't think it is best possible solution. https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/301 But it didn't work either.
I didn't find any other solutions or discussions on this topic.

Thanks for any help possible.

Comment: my guess is this: var_dump outputs immediately, while any bundle will use the given response object and add the required cors headers to it. but since you already produced output via dumps, the headers have already been set and can't be set anymore by bundles, hence no cors headers